# openvpn connecting, but now working

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

I have a working openvpn setup, that I copied from one machine to another (of course the original machine is OFF). The client connects to the server (the server was not changed), sets up the IP and routing but appart from that nothing works.

Server LAN 192.168.123.0

Client LAN 192.168.1.0

OpenVPN Client IP 192.168.123.253

```
openvpn /etc/openvpn/client.conf 
Tue Nov  8 09:50:53 2016 OpenVPN 2.3.12 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [MH] [IPv6] built on Oct 17 2016
Tue Nov  8 09:50:53 2016 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016, LZO 2.08
Tue Nov  8 09:50:53 2016 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Tue Nov  8 09:50:53 2016 Control Channel Authentication: using '/etc/openvpn/client/ta.key' as a OpenVPN static key file
Tue Nov  8 09:50:53 2016 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Nov  8 09:50:53 2016 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Nov  8 09:50:54 2016 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]XXX:XX940 [nonblock]
Tue Nov  8 09:50:55 2016 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]XXX:XX940
Tue Nov  8 09:50:55 2016 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Tue Nov  8 09:50:55 2016 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]XXX:XXXXX940
Tue Nov  8 09:50:55 2016 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=DE, ST=Bayern, L=Munich, O=nothing, OU=private, CN=private, name=private, emailAddress=XXXX
Tue Nov  8 09:50:55 2016 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=DE, ST=Bayern, L=Munich, O=nothing, OU=private, CN=server, name=private, emailAddress=XXX
Tue Nov  8 09:50:55 2016 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Tue Nov  8 09:50:55 2016 WARNING: this cipher's block size is less than 128 bit (64 bit).  Consider using a --cipher with a larger block size.
Tue Nov  8 09:50:55 2016 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Nov  8 09:50:55 2016 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Tue Nov  8 09:50:55 2016 WARNING: this cipher's block size is less than 128 bit (64 bit).  Consider using a --cipher with a larger block size.
Tue Nov  8 09:50:55 2016 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Nov  8 09:50:55 2016 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 1024 bit RSA
Tue Nov  8 09:50:55 2016 [server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]84.56.32.58:11940
Tue Nov  8 09:50:57 2016 TUN/TAP device tap0 opened
Tue Nov  8 09:50:57 2016 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Tue Nov  8 09:50:57 2016 /bin/ip link set dev tap0 up mtu 1500
Tue Nov  8 09:50:57 2016 /bin/ip addr add dev tap0 192.168.123.253/24 broadcast 192.168.123.255
Tue Nov  8 09:50:57 2016 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

also on the client, the ip is set correctly and pingable

```
ifconfig
br0: flags=4419<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::c43:1ff:fea0:26de  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 0e:43:01:a0:26:de  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 107244  bytes 65503139 (62.4 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 7740  bytes 2854919 (2.7 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::325a:3aff:fe0d:49e1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 30:5a:3a:0d:49:e1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 45013  bytes 7253888 (6.9 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 69966  bytes 62536816 (59.6 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1  (Lokale Schleife)
    RX packets 1737  bytes 155991 (152.3 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1737  bytes 155991 (152.3 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
tap0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.123.253  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.123.255
    inet6 fe80::30ff:6bff:fe1f:8503  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 32:ff:6b:1f:85:03  txqueuelen 100  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 1060  bytes 51338 (50.1 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 377  bytes 39122 (38.2 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

~ # route
Kernel IP Routentabelle
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         wan.localnet      0.0.0.0         UG    13     0        0 br0
loopback        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
loopback        localhost       255.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 lo
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.123.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tap0

 ~ # ping 192.168.123.253
PING 192.168.123.253 (192.168.123.253) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.123.253: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.245 ms
--- 192.168.123.253 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms

 ~ # ping 192.168.123.150
PING 192.168.123.150 (192.168.123.150) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- 192.168.123.150 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1074ms
```

Now my problem is that everything works fine if I try this setup on machine A, but not on Machine B. Only different point in the network configs is that on machine B, the TAP0 interface is already up and running from the network scripts (this machine also hosts 3 VMs that use the bridge)

Comment: You might need a seperate TAP interface then? There's a AddTap bat file in the openvpn client install IIRC and you can set it to use a specific one via the config file.

Comment: Can you provide the output of "iptables -vnL" from the OpenVPN server - I wonder if the new server is dropping ICMP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the client configuration file on machine B, change this statement

```
 dev tap0
```

to

```
dev tap1
```

an restart the OpenVPN. Also, remember that, if you do not instruct your Hypervisor to use the virtual interface of Openvpn (*tap1*), your VMs will **not** be routed thru the OpenVPN. I do not know what you wish, exactly...

Comment: I have now tried to change to tap10 (tap0-tap8 are created by the init scripts) and it works. it seems to make a difference which process brings up the tap interface. 

The VMs are not related to the whole openvpn scenario. they access the vpn through a seperate route

Comment: @SebastianHeyn If it works, you ought to accept my answer, by clicking on the V-shaped symbol to the left of it.

Comment: I actually did but there was a error message (maybe a bad connection)